# Confusing tag [Google-api-client]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I just ran across this tag [google-api-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-client)

Which appears to have 1,434 questions tagged under it.

### Current stats of Google APIs tags

[google-apis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apis) or [Google API's](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) is a list of API's available though Google. It is normally used to refer to the discovery services apis however i have seen it use to refer to the Google maps api as well which is not a discovery services API.  *Note for later: Google play services API is also a discovery services API.*

We have a number of tags related to these apis

- [google-drive-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-api)
- [google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api)
- [google-youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-youtube-api)
- [google-calendar-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar-api)

Google has also created a number of client libraries for use with these apis and we have tags for those as well.

- [google-api-js-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-js-client)
- [google-api-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-php-client)
- [google-api-python-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-python-client)
- [google-api-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client)
- [google-api-dotnet-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-dotnet-client)

### The problem with this tag

The problem with [google-api-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-client) tag is that people appear to be using it as a catch all for Google APIs client.  (*As in all the Google APIs client libraries*). That does not appear to be the intention of this tag the description for this tag appears to be related to something completely different.

> The GoogleApiClient The main entry point for Google Play services integration  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html

I have been working with the Google-APIs for about seven years now I currently have gold tag badge for [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) and I have never heard of anything Android related to the Google APIs.  Normally the [google-play-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play-services) tag is used for this.  It appears that someone took the GoogleApiClient.html and decided to turn it into a tag.  There may be a Google Apis Client library for android but im not an android dev so im not sure as far as i know android devs normally use the [google-api-java-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-java-client) library for android.  If there is then i would think that tag should be Google-APIS-android-client

### How to fix this.

I'm not exactly sure what to recommend in the case of this tag.  I could change the text and have it state that its for use with Google-apis-client libraries but  ...

- Do we really need a catch all tag for Google APIs Client Libraries? I am hard pressed to come up with a question that could be related to **ALL** of the client libraries.
- In the event we do the name is off as its missing the **s** it should then have been Google-api**s**-clients library tag.
- I also think its best to tag it with the language used. [google-apis-php-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apis-php-client) as the question is related to the php client library and not all of the client libraries.

I'm leaning towards saying that this tag should be completely deleted (or all questions untagged) and then pointed a synonym directly over to Google-apis tag which is the catch all tag for all google apis.  However this solution also has its draw backs as it would point a question over to [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) and not necessary a client library for Google APIs and if the question is related to a client library which language would it also then be related to.

### [Burnination Criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does not describe the question. It is extremely ambiguous.  The tag was originally meant to refer to the  Android gms common library weirdly named Google API client. This no longer exists and was deprecated years ago. See [link from the wiki for tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient)  Currently the term is used to describe Google Apis client libraries which fall under [Google discovery api](https://developers.google.com/discovery) Each library has its own tag based upon its language as seen above. So this tag is just causing confusion.

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, asking for help relating to a Google API using a client library based upon one of the [Google discovery api](https://developers.google.com/discovery) is on-topic, but there is no on-topic way of asking about Google API client libraries in general.

3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No not at all, as it's way to broad (see other points for context).

4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Questions referring to a Google API that use one of the libraries should be tagged to the language-specific library.

There is no reason to tag something with [google-api-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-client) — any anwer would be language- and library-specific.

Comment: [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) is the main class for the google play service integration. The tag should be deleted imho. Classes don't need their own tag.

Comment: Since Google [deprecated the GoogleApiClient class](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/moving-past-googleapiclient_21.html) the deletion might not be a bad idea.

Comment: Is there still nothing that can be done about this tag?

Comment: @DaImTo as a formality, can you please add answers to 4 questions outlined [in the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071)? After that, as soon as the post reaches 20 votes, it will be pretty much guaranteed to be included in the burnination process. While it make take some time to get to this tag specifically, it has a manageable amount of questions to go through, so it'll likely not be too long before it's burned. First, a mod will feature it for a day, then folks will join in by closing off-topic posts, and editing out the tag from salvageable ones.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine can you review my update.  Not 100% sure i even understand what the last point is asking.   Im happy to spend a few minutes each day in the mean time to clean it up.   My main question is how to ensure that no new questions get tagged with this after the burn.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for updating! I'll take a look shortly, but it should be enough as is from a cursory glance. Please abstain from editing it out, though, before the process reaches stage 3 (a mod will add a notice to the post) - the process for burnination is very formal (as it is enforced by the company as well), so it's considered as jumping the gun (although do feel free to edit it out if you are just editing a post as normal with other changes if you feel there are better tags - just don't target it specifically for now). As for after the burn, it should be deleted by the system after [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] 24 hours provided no new questions with it appear, but we keep watch on "zombies" both manually and with automation like Rodgort, so should be fine. There's always a chance that a user with 1.5K+ rep will recreate it, but I am personally in the process of developing a tag watcher bot to prevent these things from slipping past us. If the tag will keep reappearing despite best efforts, there is an option to request blocklisting, but that requires involvement of a community manager.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is [Rodgort](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/)

Comment: This process is fascinating. Please let me know if there is anything i can do to help or support this worthy cause.

Comment: I have updated the tag wiki for this tag [google-api-client](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-api-client/info) To point to better tagging options.

Comment: @DaImTo well, you can always participate in burninations that you find relevant to what you do; also, since you clearly make edits, retags, etc., you are already helping out a lot :) Also, if you feel like it, there are development efforts [here](https://github.com/SOTagBurners) [although we are just starting out] and [here](https://gitlab.com/rjrudman/Rodgort) [Rodgort's repository]. Plus, as usual, there's often something to help out with that's discussed in the [Burnination HQ room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)